# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String in display list view

Tags: android

**Edited**

I have the error like this 'com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String in display list view.'

Here is my class. Can someone help me out? Tks everyone!

```
public class ViewManager extends AppCompatActivity {

    private  ListView listview;
    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference ref;
    private ArrayList<String> Managername=new ArrayList<>();
//  String[] language ={"C","C++","Java",".NET","iPhone","Android","ASP.NET","PHP"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     // managerAddonDB=new ManagerAddonDB();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_manager);

        listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.managerlistview);
        firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        ref=firebaseDatabase.getReference("Manager");

        final  ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Managername);
        listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                String value=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Managername.add(value);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
    });
```

Comment: How's your data stored in "Manager" collection.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase database return data snapshot value as value pairs(Hashmap) so if you want to get that as String then use

```
String value=dataSnapshot.getValue().toString()
```

instead of

```
String value=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
```

also add a condition that data snapshot is not null.
Also check the dataSnapshot.getValue() and dataSnapshot.getValue(Java.class) function [here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot)